# How to call logging.setLogRecordFactory in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-2.x, python-logging

Given the following simple example:

```
import logging

class SmartLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    """ Dummy LogRecord example """

    def getMessage(self):
        return self.msg % self.args

logging.setLogRecordFactory(SmartLogRecord)

var = 'SmartLogRecord'
logging.warning('I am a %s', var)
```

I can run it on `Python 3` and use my custom `LogRecord` class, but `Python 2` throws an error:

```
linux@linux-PC$ python3 text.py
WARNING:root:I am a SmartLogRecord

linux@linux-PC$ python2 text.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text.py", line 9, in <module>
    logging.setLogRecordFactory(SmartLogRecord)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setLogRecordFactory'

linux@linux-PC$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.2

linux@linux-PC$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is `setLogRecordFactory()` in CPython 3.7 in all its glory:

```
# https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/29500737d45cbca9604d9ce845fb2acc3f531401/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L386
_logRecordFactory = LogRecord

def setLogRecordFactory(factory):
    global _logRecordFactory
    _logRecordFactory = factory

def getLogRecordFactory():
    return _logRecordFactory

def makeLogRecord(dict):
    rv = _logRecordFactory(None, None, "", 0, "", (), None, None)
    rv.__dict__.update(dict)
    return rv
```

Where this gets called is in Called in `Logger.makeRecord()`:

```
def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info,
               func=None, extra=None, sinfo=None):
    """
    A factory method which can be overridden in subclasses to create
    specialized LogRecords.
    """
    rv = _logRecordFactory(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func,
                           sinfo)
```

On the contrary, in Python 2, this is not a thing:

```
# https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7c2c01f02a1821298a62dd16ecc3a12da663e14b/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1261
def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None):
    """
    A factory method which can be overridden in subclasses to create
    specialized LogRecords.
    """
    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
```

What you can do is to basically *replace* the `.makeRecord()` bound method on the `Logger` object.  In other words:

```
>>> class A:
...     def f(self, a, b):
...         return a + b

>>> def new_f(self, a, b):
...     return a * b
... 
>>> A.f = new_f
>>> A().f(10, 20)
200
```

This would look like:

```
class MyLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    pass
    # override stuff here

def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None):
        print "Using a MyLogRecord instance"
        rv = MyLogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
        if extra is not None:
            for key in extra:
                if (key in ["message", "asctime"]) or (key in rv.__dict__):
                    raise KeyError("Attempt to overwrite %r in LogRecord" % key)
                rv.__dict__[key] = extra[key]
        return rv

logging.Logger.makeRecord = makeRecord
```

Illustration:

```
>>> logging.error("hello")
Using a MyLogRecord instance
ERROR:root:hello
```

In this case, you are just tailoring things to the specific need of using a single other `MyLogRecord` class.  If you really want, you could write your own `setLogRecordFactory()` as shown above, then use `_logRecordFactory` in your replacement `.makeRecord()` method, just as Python 3 is doing.

---

#### Assumption/alternatives (subclass, don't replace)

One more comment: this all assumes that you want to affect `logger` instances that are not "your own," that have been created elsewhere.  If you *only* want to affect loggers that your own code defines, you can just *subclass* `Logger` rather than completely replacing the `Logger` class that belongs to the `logging.__init__` module's namespace.